# iPhone SDK connecting to iTunes

Tags: iphone, sdk, itunes

Anybody know if there's a way to access iTunes from an iphone native program?  Is there an sdk for that?  i.e. - is there a way I can write a native iphone program and put in a 'buy' button that will bring up iTunes and go to some artist's song?  Or better yet, just buy it right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In big-iTunes, find the song your want and select Copy Link.  Put the link in your iPhone app.

You can then open this link using UIApplication's openURL: method and it will open in iTunes.